# MySQL (Get 2 tables in 1 command)

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to connect MySQL Tables I will give a example so you guys can understand my question.

### Page Table

(Use to echo the NavBar Items and )

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════╦═════════════════╗
║ ID ║  Name        ║ Type  ║ Background Image║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Home         ║ home  ║ --------------- ║
║  2 ║ AboutUs      ║ blank ║---------------- ║
║  3 ║ Services     ║ slider║---------------  ║
║  4 ║ Contacts     ║ blank ║---------------- ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════╩═════════════════╝
```

But there is a thing, we can have multiple pages with same type of page (blank,sldier ect...)

At slider we have 2 tables with information.

### Slider Settings

(Use to control the number of slider on a certain ID page)

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║  Num_Slides  ║ 
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  3 ║ 4            ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

I want to know if theres anyway to connect this db (not physicly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do just a join, something like this?

```
select * from page_table, slider_settings where page_table.id = slider_settings.id and page_table.type='slider';
```

Comment: I want to Slider_Settings just have the ID's where the type on table pages are "slider"

Comment: Modified the answer.